# Blender Python debugging with Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, blender

I'm using VS2017 with Python installed, and can debug ordinary scripts which run by Python 3.0+ However i can attach the debugger to the Blender process, where VS says i can debug Python also, there nothing happens when i start a script in Blender, nor rise exception.

Is there any way to break into the debugger like

```
int 3
```

in ASM ?

Or i'm doing something wrong ?
Thanks !

Comment: While blender includes a python interpreter, it doesn't work the same as a normal python interpreter used to run scripts. Have a look at [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81535/935) for some solutions.

Comment: @sambler Thank ! I saw this solution for VS Code, seems there is no way to use just VS